# Running unit test for angular app on tfs server

Tags: angular, unit-testing, tfs, karma-jasmine

I am  running unit test for angular app using karma and jasmine. Since karma pops up browser window, In my build definition (of tfs) to run unit test, the build gets stuck up! How to ensure it doesn't pop up a window .Instead of popping up  the results in a browser window, I want the results to be written into a file (to be specific to Junit report coverage in xml format , such that TFS server understands the file and generates report)

Comment: Have you tried configuring Karma to use a "headless" browser? You'll likely need to do this for any end-to-end tests in a CI environment, too.

Comment: yep, I agree with @jonrsharpe you should probably create a new test script like "test-build" with a different reporter, probably there's something that tfs likes.. and integrates with the pipeline to display a nice view of which unit tests passed, failed.. etc..

Comment: Can you please tell me what should be the config for karma for tfs mainly for unit test