# Running unit test for angular app modifying karma.conf.js as phantom doesn't recognize typescript spec file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, tfs, karma-jasmine

To help you answer this question, I will copy paste my karma config file, please let me know how to modify this,so that tfs understands this.

I tried adding headless browser phantom.js but still inside tfs it tries to open chrome and fails!!!

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'server/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {

        'server/**/*.js': ['coverage']
      },
      coverageReporter: {
        type : 'html',
        dir : 'coverage/'
      },

    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: false,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: true,

   concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

[link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708279/running-unit-test-for-angular-app-on-tfs-server/55709454#55709454)

Based on some of suggestion I changed karma.conf.js such that it uses phantom.js, it creates more problem, it doesn't recognize typescript files, complains entire typescript file as syntax error. Here is the modified file

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
      frameworks: ['jasmine'],
      files: [
          './app/*.spec.ts',
          './app/**/*.spec.ts'
      ],
      plugins: [
          require('karma-jasmine'),
          require('karma-webpack'),
          require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
          require('karma-tfs-reporter')
      ],
      preprocessors: {
          './app/*.spec.ts': ['webpack'],
          './app/**/*.spec.ts': ['webpack']
      },
      webpack: {
      },
      webpackMiddleware: {
          stats: 'errors-only'
      },
      browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
      reporters: ['progress', 'tfs'],
      // Default settings (optional)
      tfsReporter: {
          outputDir: 'testresults',
          outputFile: 'testresults_${date}.xml'
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: have you tried  browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],

Comment: yes I guess phantom.js has got problems,it doesn't recognize ts file

Comment: PhantomJs (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) isn't being supported anymore so it might be worth dropping it before you go to far down the hole.  I've used the ChromeHeadless and haven't seen any issues.  It just requires a bit more work if you are running it in a CI pipeline.

Comment: Thank you browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'] works